# Impossible duplicate Functional Interface resolution with lambda expressions

Tags: java, java-8

Two interfaces having the same functional signature.

Take SimpleStepBuilder.processor.

Two overloads of the same functional type.

Passing a lambda expression seems impossible.

True or false?

```
 public SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> processor(ItemProcessor<? super I, ? extends O> processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
    return this;
}

public SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> processor(Function<? super I, ? extends O> function) {
    this.itemProcessorFunction = function;
    return this;
}

public interface ItemProcessor<I, O> {
    @Nullable
    O process(I item) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: what is `ItemProcessor`?

Comment: @N.J.M. *True or false?* did you try?

Comment: @Eugene OP was probably stopped by the compiler saying it's an ambiguous call

Comment: Passing a lambda expression seems impossible.

True or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, passing any lambda `a -> a.toB()` would cause an ambiguous call.

But there are at least two options: <strike>passing an anonymous class</strike>*, casting to an appropriate type.

```
processor((Function<String, Integer>) s -> s.length());       // Function
processor((ItemProcessor<String, Integer>) s -> s.length());  // ItemProcessor
```

<sup>*It's not a lambda expression, crossed it out!</sup>

A little trick that might facilitate calls of these methods:

If `ItemProcessor` extended `Function`, it would eliminate the need of casting to `ItemProcessor`:

```
interface ItemProcessor<I, O> extends Function<I, O> {}

processor((Function<String, Integer>) String::length);  // Function
processor(s -> s.length());                             // ItemProcessor
```